# Bug em menu Responsivo

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

Estou desenvolvendo um menu responsivo aonde na versão mobile ele é chamado através de um icone, no entanto em algumas ocasiões ao redimensionarmos a pagina um evento de click deixa de funcionar e a classe (logo abaixo) .menu-mobile não é retirada

```
  <div class="nav-toggle"></div>

  <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>      
        </nav>
```

.

```
function menu (){

$('.nav-toggle').click( function () {


   if ($('.menu').hasClass('menu-mobile')) {
       $('.menu').addClass('abrir-menu').removeClass('menu-mobile');

   } else {
       $('.menu').addClass('menu-mobile').removeClass('abrir-menu');
   }  });  }



$(window).resize( function (){
      var largura = $(window).width();

      if(largura < 767){
      $('.menu').addClass('menu-mobile');
       } else {
      $('.menu').removeClass('menu-mobile abrir-menu');

}
menu();  });
```

Em resumo do código, a classe .menu-mobile serve apenas como um gatilho para executar a condicional de abrir e fechar o menu

Comment: Resolvi o problema do window resize e load, no entanto existe esse bug aonde ao redimensionar o menu em algumas situações ele não retorna ao padrão e a função de habilitar o menu é meio que "quebrada", para de funcionar. DVD, tenta executar esse codigo e ficar maximizando e diminuindo a tela em determinado momento a função para de funcionar, existe um breakpoint para as duas versões

Comment: Sempre que a tela tiver abaixo 767px a classe .menu-mobile vai ficar ativa, e ao clicar no botão ele sai e dar o lugar a .abrir-menu, ao clicar novamente o oposto acontece, criando assim um loop para abrir e fechar o menu, so que em algumas situações quando a gente aumenta e diminui o tamanho da tela isso deixa de funcionar

Comment: Bota o CSS pra gente tentar reproduzir.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema se isso for ajudar alguém no futuro aqui vai a resposta, o usuário "DVD" havia comentado que ao redimensionar a função não detectava o resize, portanto inserir um  nome a minha função window e chamei ela dentro da função menu, ficando assim :

```js
function menu (){

$('.nav-toggle').click( function () {


   if ($('.menu').hasClass('menu-mobile')) {
       $('.menu').addClass('abrir-menu').removeClass('menu-mobile');

   } else {
       $('.menu').addClass('menu-mobile').removeClass('abrir-menu');
   }  
  detectaLargura();  
 });  
 }



$(window).on('load resize', function detectaLargura (){
      var largura = $(window).width();

      if(largura < 767){
      $('.menu').addClass('menu-mobile');
       } else {
      $('.menu').removeClass('menu-mobile abrir-menu');

}
menu();  
});
```

Comment: Resolveu o problema?